# Dealing with thread in C# (deadlock)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm using thread in C# application. I have the following scenario:

The thread A, calls thread B, using this code:

```
ThreadStart t = () => StreamManager.ManageStream.mixThread(ref streamClosed, ref opEnded);
Thread threadB = new Thread(t);
threadB.Start();
```

The thread B do this work repeatedly:

```
while (!streamClosed)
    {
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
         //some stuff here
    }
opEnded = true;
```

the boolean `streamClosed` and `opEnded` are passed from thread A to thread B, by reference (using `ref` keyword)

The thread A, after starting the thread B, do the following:

```
streamClosed = true;
while(!opEnded)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait 
}
```

and the thread B stop its work. But in some situation, seems to be in deadlock, remains blocked since I kill it from the Activity Manager in Windows.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the calling code?

Comment: Are you trying to implement cooperative cancellation? There are easier ways to achieve this.

Comment: The real thread, passes also a queue ConcurrentQueue<myObjs> queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define `opEnded` as `volatile` .

It is probably being cached (by the compiler/optimizer).

---

But that is a quick and minimal fix for code that is wrong at a deeper level.

Real code shouldn't `Sleep()`. There are much better ways to makes threads sync with each other. Which one to use depends very much on what you actually want to do. You shouldn't [actually use `volatile`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, but why using volatile should help me?

Comment: It prevents the caching.

Comment: Uhm ok, but why in some situation the application works good? And only somethimes the mechanism breaks?
However I'm declaring it as static. Can I declare it as volatile in this case?

Comment: I don't know the details of 'some situation' but maybe a lock or other operation causes a memory fence under certain conditions. Iow, it depends  on `//some stuff here`

Comment: all the code inside the while is in try-catch and no exception is captureted.

Comment: I would use a `lock` instead of `volatile`. See Eric Lippert’s blog about the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Comment: Also a good read on this subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx

Comment: @ken2k How can I create a lock on bool, and then pass it to the thread?

Comment: You can't lock on a bool but any lock (on a ref type) in the code path will have the same effect, avoiding caching.